# No signal through VGA on internal graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I am currently running a zoostorm base unit a NVidia GeForce gt 520 graphics card and 4GB of RAM.

I have recently purchased the graphics card and was hoping to use a second monitor on it.

My current configuration is:
- monitor on internal VGA
- monitor on graphics card VGA

I have activated the internal graphics card in the BIOS and the monitor is shown in the display settings and also the device manager, but yet does not get signal, the computer acts like it is there but yet no signal seems to get to it.

I understand it would be easier through the HDMI on the graphics card but due to restraints on finances at the moment I am doing it this way, I can not see why this would not work as all devices are showing in the device manager I have photos which I can email as they seem to large to upload here.

If anyone can help me with this issue as I am confused and can't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

Ok a few edits 
1) its happening on a windows os 
2) all cables work as when I swap over the monitors the problem occurs on the other monitor.
3) there are no spliters involved in the config

Comment: hi thanks for the reply yes the internal is activated as this seems to be the normal resolution, and yes the cable does work as when I swap them over the problem goes to the other monitor, as I say all devices are showing up in device manager but yet cant get a signal to the monitor its on windows os

Comment: Did you ever get signal from the onboard card? I mean without the dedicated GPU plugged in and everything.

Comment: yeah I did but I lost the graphics card signal as it seems it will only activate one at a time and no matter what I did In the bias it wouldn't work so I swapped a monitor with a friend and am running hdmi out of the graphics card

Comment: Some more info can be found here https://superuser.com/questions/260634/how-can-i-set-windows-7-up-to-use-three-monitors